# Which function should I use to detect empty values in a form POST?

Tags: php, isset, string

I don't want to import blank/empty, space, null value on my database. So for this reason I want to check my input value before importing on database. Please any one can tell me isset and empty function which one is good for checking input value. here is my code. Thanks

```
$required = array('login', 'password', 'confirm', 'name', 'phone', 'email');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) {
  echo "All fields are required.";
} else {
  echo "Proceed...";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it:

```
foreach($required as $field) 
{
   $val = trim($_POST[$field];
   if (empty($val)) 
   {
      $error = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situation `empty` makes more sense, because it also checks whether the string is empty. `isset` just checks whether if it is defined. You might also want to trim the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$required = array('login', 'password', 'confirm', 'name', 'phone', 'email');

$error = false;
foreach($required as $field) {
  if (empty($_POST[$field]) || strlen(trim($_POST[$field])) == 0) {
    $error = true;
  }
}

if ($error) {
  echo "All fields are required.";
} else {
  echo "Proceed...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset` is totally useless and `empty` is perhaps not an appropriate choice here.

The values inside `$_POST` (and also `$_GET` and `$REQUEST`) are always typed as strings, so `isset` will *always* return `true`. Additionally, the behavior of `empty` on `false`, `null` and other such values does not come into play, which means that the `empty` check will only reject:

- zero-length strings
- the string `"0"`

This is different from what your code seems to intend to reject, which would be:

- zero-length strings
- strings composed entirely of whitespace

Consider using `trim($_POST['foo']) === ''` as the condition instead.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. So you tell me that isset function is totally useless. can you send me any article link about this subject

Comment: @user1493448: I tell you that `isset` is totally useless *when talking about values inside `$_POST` and friends*. This can be easily deduced from the documentation of `isset` and the fact that these values are *always* strings, which you can test yourself with `var_dump`.

Comment: @user1493448: Also, the answer you accepted (and any other solution that uses `empty`) will give an error if any field has the value `0`, which might be valid in many circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The best way might be using `empty` and `trim`. Why trim? It will remove the spaces and lines etc. from the beginning and the end. That means, when someone inserts a few spaces but no text, the spaces can be removed so you can check `empty`:

```
if(empty(trim($foo))) 
{
    // It is empty!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Isset()` checks if a variable has a value including ( Flase , 0 , or Empty string) , But not NULL.
Returns TRUE if var exists; FALSE otherwise.

`empty()` function checks if the variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False. Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

**Example:**

```
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}


// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
```

[The source](http://zainal.wordpress.com/2006/04/25/8/)

In your case, you can use `empty()` function

Answer (score -1):

You could incorporate **isNotEmpty** function

```
<?php
function isNotEmpty($input){
    $strTemp = trim($input);

    if($strTemp !== ''){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

?>

- Save isNotEmpty as 'isnotempty.php' encase you need to reference it in the future.

  ```
  include 'isnotempty.php';
  $error = false;
  foreach($required as $field) {
    if (!(isNotEmpty($_POST[$field]))) {
      $error = true;
    }

  if ($error) {
    echo "All fields are required.";
  } else {
    echo "Proceed...";
  }
  ```

Hope this helps

Comment: If you voted my answer down could you please explain what is wrong / how it could be improved?